# Why do I get this error whenever I try to use the header?

Tags: php, websocket, browser, header, phpstorm

I'm a beginner and I have just started to experiment with headers. I tried this very simple program and I just want it to say Hello, instead I get this wall of text. What's going on here and how can I fix it?

**Code:**
`<?php header("Content-Type: text/plain"); echo("Hello"); ?>`

**Expected output:**
Hello

**Actual output:**
[image: output]

I have tried to search for similar problems but I haven't been able to find one yet.

Comment: Looks like you have some JavaScript in your file. If you set the text/plain header, all contents of your file will be interpreted as plain text.

Comment: `wall of text`...it's clearly JavaScript code. So presumably the file where you've quoted the PHP code from also has other content in it, or content somehow gets injected into it. We can't see the rest of your file, and we know nothing about your environment. So you'll have to go hunting yourself for it, unless you can provide some more relevant info to us about the scenario.

Comment: My PHP file only contains the code that is included in my post...or are you talking about a different file? @ADyson

Comment: Well, does the PHP code have any `include` or `require` statements in it too? Does your webserver inject additional content into every page, perhaps? It wasn't clear if you are running this code on your local PC for testing, or on a hosted server, which might manipulate the output? Some free hosts inject advertising code and content into anything served from their domain, for example

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the PHP code does not have any of those statements, and I'm using PhpStorm's built-in web server on my local PC

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's what the internal live server injects for live reload. It just expects the pages to be HTML I suppose